# Why do folks criticise an answer in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comment

I thought the policy was to address the question rather than make criticisms of answers that are offered by other users. After all, if an answer is incorrect surely, as mathematicians we are obliged to give reasons. At least that would be constructive and may lead to a good answer. Instead I get the feeling that some users like to use comments just to negate answers and also downplay them that comes across as plain mischief making. If users know something is wrong then surely they have some inkling of a correct answer. So provide one!

Comment: In addition to my general answer, I'm guessing your question is at least motivated by [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730172/find-function-distribution/1730242#1730242). You have an answer which is technically wrong, in addition to saying "I couldn't make sense of ... but this may be a start." It's not at all surprising that you got a negative comment about this.

Comment: Agreed, but I wouldn't even call that comment negative.  Just blunt and direct.  I've been active on math.stackexchange.com for not even a month and I've seen way worse a few times already.

Comment: What got my goat was that the criticizer responded to my request that he provide a better answer to the question by going about the entire website to see if he could downgrade other posts and comments. This is what is called by psychologists as 'displacement' activity. His comment was not constructive. I stated that I hadn't checked if it was a PDF. I was well aware that it may not be correct. It is still the only answer up there. This surprises me a great deal. Why is it better to criticize rather than come up with an improvement?

Comment: @Benedict Your answer was worse than useless, it was leading in the wrong direction - you admit that you hadn't checked it was correct and that it wasn't complete, and yet are dedicated to the answer's existence. I don't understand this at all. Furthermore, Did is far from the only one in recent days to be downvoting your post; whatever armchair psychology mixed with legalese you come up with isn't going to change the reality: You are not using the site correctly.

Answer (score 13):

From the [help center page on comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), one of the main purposes of comments is to

> [l]eave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post.

Pointing out mistakes, inaccuracy, or incompleteness of answers satisfies this perfectly. There is neither an obligation nor an expectation to give a competing answer that amends the errors in another answer - and in many cases, once the author is given a chance to correct their post, such a second answer would just be unnecessary noise.

Please do not mistake a friendly, polite correction with "plain mischief making." After all, if we don't use comments to point out problems, then either incorrect answers are left alone or they are anonymously downvoted. Neither is very desirable.

Comment: Also, as a somewhat separate point: I can routinely tell that an answer is wrong without being able to answer the question myself. Glaring logical errors or off-topic answers are sometimes easy to find.

Comment: The trouble is that I don't see the comments that were made by 'Did'as constructive criticism. They are not backed up by much more than just flat contradiciton. And that is why I characterize it as 'mischief making'. Going about the website and downgrading 4 responses of mine for no reason is certainly just that.

Comment: @Benedict, the user you mention, while sometimes a bit short (and possibly a bit vague) with their comments, has in my experience always been on-point with their criticisms in the end. Our areas of interest overlap a bit, so I have read many such comments by them. From my perspective the problems pointed out by their mathematical comments are largely real and often severe to the point of being misleading. I don't mean to speak for them but I am sure that their main intention is to ensure that inaccuracies are not left to fester on this site, NOT to be vindictive or to harass you in any way.

Comment: @Benedict You still haven't really addressed the fact that some of your answers are *actually wrong*. Rather than trying to find some site policy that the commenter is violating, you ought to actually correct the error they point out. And keep in mind that the other users are under no obligation to fix the errors in your post. You're spending significantly more time criticizing and insulting other users ("little chap," "vindictive, ignorant little boy," etc.), which is completely inappropriate and abusive. You are the one in the wrong here.

Comment: I only just noticed this post in meta, and as I believe myself to be the original individual who responded (with a comment) to the answer posted by this user, I am wholly perplexed by the situation, since I am not Did, and I have no idea how I could have elicited this kind of reaction.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Not that it matters much but, now that the heat is gone, would you have specific examples of "possibly a bit vague" comments?

Comment: @Did I haven't been using the site much recently so any specific examples have faded from my memory :). I was hoping the double modifiers "sometimes" and "possibly" would say that it's rare, and really I mainly said it to try to sympathize with Benedict, not as a direct criticism. Hope I didn't offend.

Comment: @AntonioVargas You saw fit to state that something exists, which you had no example of in mind at the time and which you cannot recollect any occurrence of now? Cannot say I agree.

Comment: @Did if you must take offense then that's your perogative. I was basing it on a general impression, not a specific example.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Who is "possibly a bit vague" now? More seriously, you feel at ease with ascribing mathematical vagueness to someone's comments, with no data at hand?

Comment: @Did just leaving this comment to say that I won't be responding further to this.